# android ndk : dlopen failed: cannot locate "hb_ft_face_create"

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, harfbuzz

it work well in androd 4.0, but in android 4.4 and 5.0 it error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "hb_ft_face_create" referenced by "libHelloWorld.so"...

i build share library （harfbuzz-ng.so）, hb_ft_face_create is in harfbuzz-ng.so, and HelloWorld.so is use the function hb_ft_face_create() and hb_ft_font_create()。

but Other function work well。i test in ndk10 and ndk11.

Comment: You should post the relevant code and makefile(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 'hb_buffer_destroy'. 
I guess the problem is some functions' declaration are not compiled and attached to the harfbuzz.so file.
I could manage to solve My problem by compiling the Harfbuzz library from scratch and statically link it to my NDK library. (STATIC instead of SHARED)